# How to change text every 24 hours in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So basically I am creating an app, and on the homepage of the app there is a "Quote of the Day". I have the quote already in a container but I can not get the quote to change every 24 hours.

I am new to Dart, but using past knowledge on other programming languages, I figured I needed to use an if-else statement that also uses the device's internal clock. I was thinking that it would be "If(0:00 AM){display next quote in array} else{do nothing}".

```
import 'dart:async';

void main () => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: MainActivity(),
    );
  }
}

class MainActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainActivityState createState() => _MainActivityState();
}

class _MainActivityState extends State<MainActivity>
{
  String _timeString;

  @override
  void initState(){
    _timeString = "${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute}";
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (Timer t)=>_getCurrentTime());
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('assets/Day.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
          new Center(
            child:new Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 100.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    offset: new Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                    blurRadius: 5.0
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text(
                _timeString,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                  fontSize: 50
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 300),           
          new Container(
              width: 345.0,
              height: 120.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    offset: new Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                    blurRadius: 5.0
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text(
                '“Morning is an important time of day, because how you spend your morning can often tell you what kind of day you are going to have.”\n\t ― Lemony Snicket, The Blank Book',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Playfair Display'
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 void _getCurrentTime()  {
    setState(() {
  _timeString = "${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute}";
    });
  } 
}
```

No matter how many times I try, this approach doesn't work, but that may be due to my limited knowledge. Any bit of information helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 variables.

One to store the previous timestamp of when user entered the app and one to store the current timestamp. Set the previous timestamp's value once your done with the checking the below condition.

If the two days of the 2 timestamps are different then request for a random quote.

Use SharePreferences to store the previous quotes locally if your worried that the user might play with his phones time.

If you want a specific quote to be shown each day then store key pair or index pair or date-quote pair value for each quote and first request for the index/key/date, if it is equal to the old index/key/date value stored in the user's phone then don't request for a new quote else request for the required quote and use the index you have for reference.

The above approach might seem better than the previous one but keep one thing in your mind that everyone like in a different timezones.

Comment: I haven't included the code as it includes server side code too which depends on what service your using.

Answer (score 0):

please use package https://github.com/rmawatson/flutter_isolate

for demo, I display time info every one second, you can change per your request. 
If you do this with isolate only,after you press power button and screen become black for more than 15 minutes. you job will stop. 
use this package can prevent this, your job will continue running after 15 minutes.

```
Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      counter++;
      String msg = "${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute} ${DateTime.now().second}"; //'notification ' + counter.toString();
      print('SEND: ' + msg);
      sendPort.send(msg);
      //sendPort.send(counter);
    });
```

full code, click floating action button to start

```
import 'package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:isolate';
//import 'package:screen/screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Isolate Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Isolates'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FlutterIsolate _isolate;
  bool _running = false;
  static int _counter = 0;
  String notification = "";
  ReceivePort _receivePort;

  void _start() async {
    _running = true;
    _receivePort = ReceivePort();
    _isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(_checkTimer, _receivePort.sendPort);
    _receivePort.listen(_handleMessage, onDone:() {
      print("done!");
    });
  }

  static void _checkTimer(SendPort sendPort) async {
    int counter = 0;
    Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      counter++;
      String msg = "${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute} ${DateTime.now().second}"; //'notification ' + counter.toString();
      print('SEND: ' + msg);
      sendPort.send(msg);
      //sendPort.send(counter);
    });
  }

  void _handleMessage(dynamic data) {
    print('RECEIVED:  ${data}');
    setState(() {
      notification = data.toString();
    });
  }

  void _stop() {
    if (_isolate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _running = false;
        notification = '';
      });
      _receivePort.close();
      //_isolate.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);
      _isolate.kill();
      _isolate = null;
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              notification,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _running ? _stop : _start,
        tooltip: _running ? 'Timer stop' : 'Timer start',
        child: _running ? new Icon(Icons.stop) : new Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]